# How to create a batch file for connecting to Java DB Network Server

Tags: java, batch-file, netbeans, derby

I have made a Netbeans application that is reliant on the DB Network Server in order to retrieve data. In Netbeans the code works fine and runs well. Outside of Netbeans everything but the database information is working. I have made a batch file for connecting to the localhost server that seems to connect on the port I assigned: 1527. Even after connecting to the localhost, it won't display the database information.
My code in the batch file:

```
PATH C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\db\bin;%PATH%

startNetworkServer
```

When I run this I get the result:

```
Security manager installed using the Basic server security policy.

Apache Derby Network Server - 10.10.1.8 - (1557168) started and ready to accept connections on port 1527connect
```

Is there more code that I need to add in order to connect to the actual database itself from the server? Or is this not the right way to do this at all? I have tried using the Embedded DB but that didn't work and only caused more problems. I would prefer greatly to stay away from it and stick to the Network DB.

Comment: It looks like you have successfully started the Derby Network Server, from the output of your startup command. So what precise error do you get in your application? Be sure to unwind the exception to discover the details: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain

Comment: Please review [Ask] and [MCVE].  The output you show us seems to indicate that everything is working correctly.  Does your netbeans code fail to connect?  Is the network server running as a service?